# Proving that if $C_1\subset C_2$ then $f(C_1)\subset f(C_2)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question from homework that I don't understand how to solve. I think I know the answer but I don't know how to prove it in a formal way. We are given that $f\colon A\to B$ is a function and $C_1$ and $C_2$ are subsets of $A$.

Now I need to prove if this statement is true or false:

> If $C_1\subset C_2$ then $f(C_1)\subset f(C_2)$.

Comment: A different approach: Suppose $C_1\subset C_2$. Furthermore, suppose $\gamma\in f(C_1)$; that is, $\gamma=f(c)$ for some $c\in C_1$. Since $C_1\subset C_2$, we know $c\in C_1\to c\in C_2$. Thus, $\gamma\in f(C_2)$ for some $c\in C_2$, namely the $c$ in $C_1$. Since $\gamma\in f(C_1)\to\gamma\in f(C_2)$, it is clear that $f(C_1)\subset f(C_2)$, as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $f(C_1) = \{f(c) : c \in C_1\}$.

Since $C_1 \subset C_2$, we can write $\{f(c) : c \in C_1\} \subset \{f(c) : c \in C_2\} = f(C_2)$, i.e. $f(C_1) \subset f(C_2)$.